# Render partial along with another object

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my controller method:

```
def update
  @properties = Property.all
  @user = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render partial: 'property_all' }
  end
end
```

While rendering partial, can I also render another object something like below which can be captured in AJAX request?

```
format.js { render partial: 'property_all', user: @user }
```

**AJAX**:

```
success : function (response, object) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass any variables to it like this:

```
render partial: 'property_all', locals: { user: @user }
```

You can also use this shorter form if the only two arguments to render are the two above:

```
render 'property_all', user: @user
```

Comment: i dont want to pass variable to partial. After render partial, i want to pass it to ajax along with `@user` object.

Comment: "passing it to ajax" - do you want to respond to the request with a @user in json format, or in html or some other format? You do realize that a controller can only render once, right?

Comment: i am not sure ..but i possible i want to respond to the request with both partial object and @user object . I am not sure if its possible or not ..Thats why i am asking this question

Comment: I can't answer the question if you're not sure whether the front end expects HTML or JSON from the server. That should be specified in the ajax request. How you include information in the response depends on the format.